# on scroll set background-color on element box which is on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think the code shows what I am trying to do.

html:

```
<div id="one" class="box"></div>
<div id="two" class="box"></div>
<div id="thr" class="box"></div>
<div id="fou" class="box"></div>
<div id="fiv" class="box"></div>
<div id="six" class="box"></div>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $('.box').each(functions(e){
            if($(this).offset().top <= 0) {
                $(this).css('background-color','green');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

css:

```
div {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background-color:orange;
    margin:10px;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VR4ca/

So while scrolling the box on top should become the background-color green until the next box reaches the top of the window

Please help

it is not even working just with the first box http://jsfiddle.net/VR4ca/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var pixelScrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    $( ".box" ).each(function( index ) {
    var currentHeight = $(this).height();
        if (pixelScrolled >= index * currentHeight)
            $(this).addClass('active');
        else
            $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Instead of .height() you can use .outerHeight() or .outerHeight(true) to include the size of border, padding and margin.

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kapuzencharly/VR4ca/7/):

Answer (score 2):

If you want to always have the upper green so something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        num=Math.ceil($(window).scrollTop()/$('.box').height());
        $('.box').css('background-color','orange');
        $('.box:nth-child('+num+')').css('background-color','green');      
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pesulap/VR4ca/9/)

cleaner solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        num=Math.trunc($(window).scrollTop()/$('.box').height());
        $('.box').css('background-color','').eq(num).css('background-color','green');      
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pesulap/VR4ca/10/)

Comment: thank you soo much! really appreciate this awesome solution. I forogot to mention in the question, the .boxes can vary in height..  thats why jochen answer worked better for me